# Getting the tutorial SocketIO to work

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to get the example from SocketIO working on my domain.

I have managed to get Node.JS installed, along with ExpressJS and SocketIO through the command line.

Now, I am trying to get this to run.  On the server side I have:

(located in /nodejs, at the same level as /public_html, not inside it)

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And then on the client side I have:

(Located in /public_html/socketio.htm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Socket IO Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

    <style type='text/css'>
        * {font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Socket IO Test</h1>
    <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand the following questions:

**1.** Does it matter where my node.js runs from? Should I put it inside /public_html?

**2.** I couldn't list on port 80, I got the error address in use.  It seems to me that that is a common port to use for http traffic, why would SocketIO use that?  Or is it because I am running my nodejs outside of a domain? Should I create a subdomain and move my nodejs files (including /node_modules) to a subdomain?

**3.**  What port can I use? I tried 3000, and then changing the `http://localhost/` to `http://localhost:3000` but that didn't work.

**4.** I am not running on a local machine, but on my domain.  Do I need to change `http://localhost/` to reflect that? Aka, `http://domain.com` ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You can only have one listener at a time for a given port per ip address.  Further, port numbers below 1024 require a higher level of privilege to listen to in most operating systems.  If you're getting address in use, that must mean some other process is already listening to port 80 on this server.

Comment: 1. Don't put it in `public_html`, that's for apache I think. You shouldn't use it. I'd recommend creating a folder for node scripts inside of the home directory (`~`), for example, you could store your node scripts in `~/node-stuff`. 2. port 80 is probably already in use. It's the standard port for listening on http, so if you have apache running like I think you might, you'll want to turn that off. You also need to run your script with root permissions to listen on port 80, but this is VERY unsafe. So, usually, you'll want to listen on a higher port (above 1024), and then use  a proxy or

Comment: (continued) iptables to reroute it to port 80. But for now, while testing, just run it on a high port. `3000` will work. I prefer `1337`. I wonder why...:). 3. Just double check that you change the URL when connecting in your browser, change the port in `server.listen`, and also change the URL in `io.connect`. Otherwise...who knows? 4. Yes, you would need to change it. If your project becomes big, I would recommend using a global variable to store the hostname (`var hostname='http://localhost/'`) and then use that variable (`io.connect(hostname)`), then you only have to change it once.

Comment: i think , you should change in your socketio.htm , io.connect('http://localhost/') to io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080') or if you have  ip addres you should use it maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server side ..

```
var app = require('express')();
var express = require("express")
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/nodejs'));


server.listen(8000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

client side..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Socket IO Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

    <style type='text/css'>
        * {font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Socket IO Test</h1>
    <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and use directory structure as follow..

- expressocket.js
- nodejs/

  ```
        socketio.htm
  ```